# AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize("user") . how to get a unique userID for every user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth

The input of my app is a Google Sheet URL, it can get the credential and read the content of the sheet.
When my app uses Oauth2.0 to get authorization from users, I use example code from Google Document below. As for every user, I want to store a unique credential so that when one user request multiple times to my app, so I don't have to create and store new credential every time(Actually this part is implemented in AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user"), it will create a new credential when the "user" does not have one). 
In the example code, I think it doesn't consider the situation when multiple users send requests to my app, the "user" can not be the userID for multiple users, So the "user" must adjust for every user, which means it can not be constant. 
Because the credential is stored locally, if the same user request multiple times in a short time, user don't have to be redirected to Google signIn page to grant authorization to my app. 
MY question is what can I do to give every different user a unique userID when multiple users call my endpoint, it is possible that every user can input multiple url in a short period of time.

I have an idea that if Google API has a method that it can get the user's unique information before get the credential, like the username of userID.

```
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = KirbyGsheet.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9998).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by extract user's information from front-end to make a unique ID, then send this ID and url to back-end